# Android app cannot update from market, after shareduserid added

Tags: android, google-play, adb, android-manifest

I added shareduserid to my apps, when trying to update app from google play store I get -504 error.Device log is below. Manifest file is correct and when install from android studio or adb there is no problem but can not update from market. Any ideas?

```
Copying /data/data/io.crash.air/files/com.xxx.xxx_36fcadf21b0a4ef18ff35b90608b3b1c.apk to base.apk
D/PackageManager(  645): Renaming /data/app/vmdl1037256928.tmp to /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-2
I/ActivityManager(  645): Force stopping com.xxx.xxx appid=10271 user=-1: uninstall pkg
I/PackageManager(  645): Package com.xxx.xxx codePath changed from /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1 to /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-2; Retaining data and using new
W/PackageManager(  645): Package com.xxx.xxx shared user changed from <nothing> to com.yyy.yyy; replacing with new
W/PackageManager(  645): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-2
W/PackageParser(  645): Unknown element under <application>: intent-filter at /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-1/base.apk Binary XML file line #334
D/ActivityManager(  645): getTaskThumbnailLocked mainThumbnail is null, TaskRecord{2732f83e #5724 A=com.xxx.xxx U=0 sz=0}
D/ActivityManager(  645): getTaskThumbnailLocked mainThumbnail is null, TaskRecord{2732f83e #5724 A=com.xxx.xxx U=0 sz=0}
I/PackageManager(  645): Successfully restored package : com.xxx.xxx after failed upgrade
```

Comment: "I added shareduserid to my apps" -- do not do that. You cannot reliably change `android:sharedUserId`. Whatever you ship with originally must be the value you use forever for that app. This is one of the reasons why IMHO ordinary Android SDK app developers should not mess with `android:sharedUserId`.

Comment: I have changed and published in store, users cant install update unless uninstall old one.I have 1million+ users and can wait everyone uninstall and install my app. Is there any way to resolve? If I update again with removed shareduserid that time current updated users cannot install this update @CommonsWare

Comment: As far as I am aware, you are screwed, and I do not have any suggestions on how best to repair the damage, sorry.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare :)

Comment: I also had the same problem. Opened a ticket to Google. The issue number is 209591 at https://code.google.com/p/android/ portal. I hope google solve it soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If sharedUserId is added or removed from the AndroidManifest, users will not be able to update the application because the OS userid the Android OS is assigning to the application has changed.

Unfortunately for the users, at this point they can only move forward by doing an uninstall and re-install. There are no ways for you to fix this so that they can do an update.

I am really, really sorry this happened to you and your users. I have asked Google Play to add a warning to the Dev Console that alerts developers about this.

Take some cold comfort in the fact that you are not the only one who has had this issue. I've been there, and it sucks.